# Scrapy spider close prematurely

Tags: python, scrapy

I've programmed Scrapy to scrap a couple of thousand url link that I've stored on the  database. I've programmed a spider to call scrapy.Requests function to be passed with url from the database.However after scraping 1-2 page the spider closes prematurely (without error). I don't know why this happened. 
Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import olsDBUtil
import tokopediautil
from datetime import datetime
import time

import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


class DataproductSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    dbObj = olsDBUtil.olsDBUtil()
    name = "dataProduct"
    allowed_domains = ["tokopedia.com"]
    newProductLink = list(dbObj.getNewProductLinks(10))
    start_urls = list(newProductLink.pop())
    # start_urls = dbObj.getNewProductLinks(NumOfLinks=2)

    tObj = tokopediautil.TokopediaUtil()

    configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='log.txt',
        format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )


    def parse(self, response):

        if response.status == 200:
            thisIsProductPage = response.selector.xpath("/html/head/meta[@property='og:type']/@content").extract()[
                                    0] == 'product'
            if thisIsProductPage:
                vProductID = self.dbObj.getProductIDbyURL(response.url)
                vProductName = \
                response.selector.xpath("//input[@type='hidden'][@name='product_name']/@value").extract()[0]
                vProductDesc = response.selector.xpath("//p[@itemprop='description']/text()").extract()[0]
                vProductPrice = \
                response.selector.xpath("/html/head/meta[@property='product:price:amount']/@content").extract()[0]
                vSiteProductID = \
                response.selector.xpath("//input[@type='hidden'][@name='product_id']/@value").extract()[0]
                vProductCategory = response.selector.xpath("//ul[@itemprop='breadcrumb']//text()").extract()[1:-1]
                vProductCategory = ' - '.join(vProductCategory)
                vProductUpdated = \
                response.selector.xpath("//small[@class='product-pricelastupdated']/i/text()").extract()[0][26:36]
                vProductUpdated = datetime.strptime(vProductUpdated, '%d-%M-%Y')
                vProductVendor = response.selector.xpath("//a[@id='shop-name-info']/text()").extract()[0]

                vProductStats = self.tObj.getItemSold(vSiteProductID)
                vProductSold = vProductStats['item_sold']
                vProductViewed = self.tObj.getProductView(vSiteProductID)
                vSpecificPortalData = "item-sold - %s , Transaction Sucess - %s , Transaction Rejected - %s " % (
                vProductStats['item_sold'], vProductStats['success'], vProductStats['reject'])

                print "productID      : " + str(vProductID)
                print "product Name   : " + vProductName
                print "product Desc   : " + vProductDesc
                print "Product Price  : " + str(vProductPrice)
                print "Product SiteID : " + str(vSiteProductID)
                print "Category       : " + vProductCategory
                print "Product Updated: " + vProductUpdated.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                print "Product Vendor : " + vProductVendor
                print "Product Sold   : " + str(vProductSold)
                print "Product Viewed : " + str(vProductViewed)
                print "Site Specific Info: " + vSpecificPortalData

                self.dbObj.storeNewProductData(
                    productID=vProductID,
                    productName=vProductName,
                    productPrice=vProductPrice,
                    productSiteProdID=vSiteProductID,
                    productVendor=vProductVendor,
                    productDesc=vProductDesc,
                    productQtyDilihat=vProductViewed,
                    productTerjual=vProductSold,
                    productCategory=vProductCategory,
                    productSiteSpecificInfo=vSpecificPortalData

                )

                self.dbObj.storeProductRunningData(
                    productID=vProductID,
                    productDilihat=str(vProductViewed),
                    productTerjual=str(vProductSold)

                )

        else:
            print "Error Logged : Page Call Error"

        LinkText = str(self.newProductLink.pop())
        print "LinkText : %s" % LinkText
        print "Total newProductLink is %s" % str(len(self.newProductLink))

        yield scrapy.Request(url=LinkText, callback=self.parse)
```

Here's the scrapy Log :

```
INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: tokopedia)
INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tokopedia.spiders', 'HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS': 1800, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tokopedia.spiders'], 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'tokopedia', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}
INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
INFO: Spider opened
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tokopedia.com/karmedia/penjelasan-pembatal-keislaman> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): js.tokopedia.com
DEBUG: https://js.tokopedia.com:443 "GET /productstats/check?pid=27455429 HTTP/1.1" 200 61
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.tokopedia.com
DEBUG: https://www.tokopedia.com:443 "GET /provi/check?pid=27455429&callback=show_product_view HTTP/1.1" 200 31
INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 333,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20815,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 10, 18, 4, 10, 355000),
 'httpcache/firsthand': 1,
 'httpcache/miss': 1,
 'httpcache/store': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 10, 18, 4, 8, 922000)}
INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Can you share logs and stats at the end?

Comment: Hello Paul... sorry I am new to scrapy.. how do I check out the logs on scrapy?

Comment: Your spider has only 1 URL to fetch apparently, https://www.tokopedia.com/toko388/tile-8x17 . And your `parse` callback does not generate new `scrapy.Request`. Check your `start_urls`, or even better, implement a `start_requests()` method to iterate over your URLs from the database like [in the docs' example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider)

Comment: Hi Paul... why is that yah? On the last part of the code it did call scrapy.Request which callback to the parse function :                               yield Request(url=str(LinkText), callback=self.parse)

Comment: It seems to me that your `yield Request` is inside the `else` block of `if response.status == 200:`, which you probably not getting in since you get an HTTP 200

Comment: I shall try to implement the start_requests function as you've suggested, but I wanna get good with Python and scrapy framework.. I  definitely would like to know why my code hasn't work as it should have..

Comment: Hi Paul.. Thanks so much for helping me. I've cleaned up the code.. to make it closer to the else statement.. and to make sure that the request call is not within the else statement as you pointed out. But the problem still persis.

Comment: You may have to run with a debugger to understand what's happening. You could convert your print statements to logging calls perhaps. Another thing to try: what happens if you simply yield the next product URL in your callback, without any parsing, does it fetch more pages?

Answer (score 1):

Changed the scrapy.Request call to absolute url link for the next product.. it worked. I don't understand why this happens.. somehow the list.pop() statement doesn't work.. even though I've change it to a string.

Comment: When I print get product List it shows this :    [('https://www.tokopedia.com/ladybeautysmart/htmh-005-pesona-asli-htmh-005-theraskin-cream-malam-htmh',), ('https://www.tokopedia.com/supplierkosmetik/tahap-1-been-pink-cream-bpom-original-new-baby-pink',), ('https://www.tokopedia.com/marieshop/nomor-16-limited-kissproofkisprofkiss-profkis-proof',)]

Comment: is this a tuple within a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dont_filter=True` in your `scrapy.Request()`. I was having a similar issue with the duplicate filter causing the spider (also using `pop()`) to close prematurely and I see you have an `'offsite/filtered': 1` there that may have caused a filtering issue.